# Not possible to print Unicode A729 character in LaTeX

Tags: unicode

I tried to display the latin small letter tz - ꜩ with their respective [unicode](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EA%9C%A9) with \symbol or \char but it does not work when I try it in Overleaf.

I looked at the conversion [tool](https://www.johndcook.com/unicode_latex.html) if there is a corresponding LaTeX symbol but it seems there is none.

Is there a way for displaying it in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us whether you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX to compile your document.

Comment: Hello, I have pdfLaTeX set as compiler for my document in Overleaf.

Comment: I would suggest [LaTeX-IPA](https://ctan.org/pkg/tipa) but I can't found tzlig in the documentation and can't try from the box i'm answering from now (maybe later.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're free to use either LuaLaTeX of XeLaTeX, all you need to do is load the `fontspec` package and specify a font package that features the glyph `ꜩ`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
ꜩ \quad \char"A729
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok got it thanks! It works indeed with another compiler. I need to verify if I wont encounter any other issues with the compiler change. Just another question though: If I use another font in my document then setmainfont changes the font of my whole document. Is there a way to only use the font in one section for the glyph I want to add?

And second question, when I stay with pdfLaTeX then its not possible to use this glyph at all? Thank you!

Comment: @Zitar - On your second question: The answer depends o which font(s) you employ. On your first question: Yes, `\setmainfont` generally affects the entire document. For ways to limit the font change to just one glyph, please peruse the user guide of the [fontspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package, especially the section on the `\newfontfamily` command.

Comment: Regarding font I use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} only. Thanks for linking the guide I will take a look.

Answer (score 7):

The tz ligature is common in German blackletter scripts (Gebrochene Schriften). Packages for pdfLaTeX that provide such scripts ligate tz accordingly (but not for all scripts). The resulting character looks rather different from regular Latin script but in certain situations it may be useful.

Example with `yfonts`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}
\noindent Normal text in Computer Modern\\
\textgoth{The tz ligature in Gothic}\\
\textswab{No tz ligature in Swabacher}\\
\textfrak{The tz ligature in Fraktur}\\
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: these fonts look wonderful!

Comment: Yes it looks too different but interesting overall!

Answer (score 4):

I know of no font for pdfLaTeX that supports the character. A not so bad replacement can be built as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[X2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\tz}{t\kern-0.15em{\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\symbol{"A7}}}
\newunicodechar{ꜩ}{\tz}

\begin{document}

\tz\ \textit{\tz}

ꜩ \textit{ꜩ}

\end{document}
```

The `newunicodechar` parts are optional, but of course without them you can only use `\tz`.

[image]

The amount of kerning might need to be adjusted for different font families.

Comment: thank you very much!